# Why doesn't Hulk's ablilities affect Bruce?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, regeneration

Why is that the gamma in Hulk not affect Banner? Is it that when epinephrine is released it collides with gamma and create the effects with Hulk and then separate with Banner?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  The radiation created the Hulk, so I'm not sure what you're asking...

Answer (score 2):

the radiation burst mutated Banner's endocrine system

when Banner gets ticked off instead of a normal flight or fight adrenal response Banner's brain releases massive amounts of assorted chemicals that causes the hulk mutation

Comment: Don't forget pain. Physical pain can also trigger an adrenal response, which in Banner releases said chemicals instead. This is what happens to him in the recent *Avengers* film.